# Eclipse: Have multiple Dynamic web projects contribute to a single war file?

Tags: java, dynamic, jakarta-ee, war

I am in a situation where I basically want to be able to have a web project in Eclipse where the WebContents folder is merged from multiple projects instead of only a single dynamic web project.

If I have "a.jsp" in project A, and "b.jsp" in project B, I would like to end up with a single web application in the web container where "a.jsp" and "b.jsp" sit next to each other in the same folder.  It would be perfect if all files, not just the jsp-files, could be merged like this.

This is to be able to have a core version of our application but being able to handle customer specific changes easily.

I know I can do this with suitable ant magic, but we want to have something that works well for our current Eclipse based development process.  We will use JSR-330 dependency injection on Java classes, and essentially I'd like something along the lines of dependency injection but just for any resource and not just classes.

Can Eclipse do this?

If Eclipse cannot, would an EAR deployment be suitable perhaps?  I currently have experience with WAR's only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Maven is an option, then Maven [overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) would be perfect here and it should theoretically be supported by the m2eclipse plugin. But I don't have any experience with that and there might be some issues (see [MNGECLIPSE-599](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-599)) so this would require some testing.

Nevertheless, the comments of [MNGECLIPSE-599](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-599) are pretty interesting, especially this one:

> Any love for this issue? Our entire team has moved to Netbeans for WAR development because of this. We are basically waiting for Servlet 3.0 to solve this issue for us (Servlet 3.0 would effectively negate our need to do overlays in Maven) Our company is big on reducing copy-paste so we use overlays to manage WAR media that must be common in our apps.

The way Java EE 6 would make overlays obsolete is not crystal clear for me (through Web Fragments?) but the fact is that [Eclipse's WTP release with Java EE 6 support has been delayed to **June 2010**](http://blog.arungupta.me/2009/09/totd-102-java-ee-6-servlet-3-0-and-ejb-3-1-wizards-in-eclipse/). So, until then, you'll need extra tooling (e.g. maven overlays) or should maybe consider switching to NetBeans.

Comment: maven is not an option unless we absolutely, unavoidably have to.  We are not tempted by the maven way of life :)

The reason for JEE6 is that we would like to push the web service stack, dependency injections and JSF 2.0 into the container instead of deploying suitable implementations inside the WAR.  From my investigations today I do not think the time is right yet for that.

Comment: Thanks for the mentioning of Servlet 3.0 to resolve something.  I'll look into it.

Comment: We migrated to maven and ended up doing exactly this.  Thanks.

Comment: Note, m2e needed to become good enought first.  That happened within the last year.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar use case which I successfully resolved by using (as Pascal suggested) Maven.
I have a root web project (which also works standalone) and for each client I have a separate web project which is configured to overlay with the root web project. Furthermore, since each client has several environments I created a maven profile for each environment (test, prod, local, ...). I documented this a bit so if ever you are interested I don't mind mailing you the doc.

Comment: I would suggest you write it up in a blog.  This is something that any non-trivial project needs to be able to handle.

Comment: Good idea, any suggestions for a community/maven blog I can use?

Answer (score 0):

- you don't need to change your "eclipse based development process" to use ant. Just register an Ant builder (`right click project > Properties > Builders`) and integrate the ant script with your eclipse process
- you can use maven's multi-module options. (The maven plugin for eclipse is very good as well)
- use can also use [FileSync](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/index.html) - not industry-standard but pretty powerful. It's used for developing on `localhost`, of course.

Here are a few tips for using FileSync:

- setup which files/file patterns/dirs to copy to a target directory (Tomcat's `webapps/application` in your case). So as soon as you press "save", the files are copied.
- make all absolute paths in the `FileSync.xxxx.prefs` relative by introducing a Linked Resource (`preferences > workspace > linked resources`), and using the link resource variable in the prefs file (lets call it `WEBAPP_HOME`)
- commit the `FileSync.xxxx.prefs` file
- tell each developer on the team to configure the `WEBAPP_HOME` variable. Thus the setup will not be valid for only one machine, but for each machine in the team.

Comment: Do you have experience with an ant builder when doing web application development?  We currently use Tomcat, but for JSR-330 reasons we consider migrating to Glassfish.  I am especially interested in the turnaround time - press Ctrl-S, and reload in browser.

Comment: I have experience with maven and with the newly-added option - FileSync.I use maven for creating a build, and FileSync for CTRL + S stuff. It's pretty powerful - you just configure it to move files from each project to a common target dir.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the servlet 3.0 "Resources in bundled jar files" feature.
With this feature you can include web resources (html/xhtml/css/js/jpg/etc) in jar files (along with java class files, of course) and the web server will search the "META-INF/resources" folders of the jars for the resources.

More details here:

http://alvinjayreyes.com/2013/07/28/servlet-3-0/